# How to use a bunch of clause in a having statement. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

assume i have a query like this:

```
SELECT table1.id 
FROM (
       SELECT id, sum(column) as A 
       FROM table1 
       GROUP BY id 
     ) a1
Left join (
       SELECT id, 
       sum(column) as B 
       FROM table 2 
       GROUP BY Id 
    ) a2
    on table1.id=table2.id

.

.

.

.

Left join (
            SELECT id, sum(column) as G 
            FROM table 7
            GROUP BY id
          ) g1
          on table1.id=table7.id 

Having or where A+B - (C+D+E+F+G) >0
```

I tried both, none works.

Having return error on there's no group by in the first select and where doesn't return any rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juan has the right answer. I am just adding a SQLFiddle to help strengthen his answer. Please look at a smaller instance of the same solution here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/81c275/1

**Tables**

```
create table table1(id int, col int);
insert into table1 values (1, 10);
insert into table1 values (2, 20);
insert into table1 values (2, 30);

create table table2(id int, col int);
insert into table2 values (1, 5);
insert into table2 values (2, 3);
insert into table2 values (2, 2);

create table table3(id int, col int);
insert into table3 values (1, 100);
insert into table3 values (2, 20);
insert into table3 values (2, 3);
```

**SQL**

```
select a1.id
from (select id, sum(col) as A from table1 group by id) a1
left join (select id, sum(col) as B from table2 group by id) a2
  on a1.id = a2.id
left join (select id, sum(col) as C from table3 group by id) a3
  on a1.id = a3.id
where A + B - (C) > 0
```

You can add more tables in the SQLFiddle with whatever values you please, and change the SQL accordingly by appending D, E, F, G etc after C in `(C)`.

The above example will result in output of 2 since ID 2's A+B = 55 and C = 23. A+B-C > 0 for this record and therefore the output will be 2.

Answer (score 2):

First your question have some issues.

- I'm going to guess you mean put alias a, b, c, d ....
  instead of a1, a2, g1.
- Also your left join should be something like `a.id = b.id` at the moment you create a subquery you have to use the alias instead of tablename.

If you fix that you should add a `WHERE`, I also guess you mean use the SUM() result

```
WHERE a.A + b.B - (c.C+ d.D+ e.E+ f.F+ g.G) > 0
```

.

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM (
       SELECT id, sum(column) as sumA 
       FROM table1 
       GROUP BY id 
     ) a
Left join 
    (
       SELECT id, sum(column) as sumB 
       FROM table 2 
       GROUP BY Id 
    ) b
    on a.id = b.id

.    

.

.

.

Left join 
      (
        SELECT id, sum(column) as sumG 
        FROM table 2 
        GROUP BY id
      ) g
      on f.id = g.id 

WHERE a.sumA + b.sumB - (c.sumC + d.sumD + e.sumE + f.sumF + g.sumG) >0
```

Comment: Having doesn't work cuz there's no group by. Where doesn't return any results. When i put A,B,..,G in the select and calculate the formula in excel there are 500 rows

Comment: see my suggest query i just add.

Comment: Dear carlos, how is your answer different from my question? My problem isn't aliasing or using better names. It's just an example

Comment: Well a better example will help to see the problem. You use `on table1.id = table2.id` on the left join and that is wrong. Because you dont have table1 or table2 in your `FROM` clausule. You only have the alias `a,b,c,d,e,f` ... And also at the end you should use `alias.Variable` instead of `Variable` to avoid ambigous but that is just me.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you need to take out the 'where' and move it up if you still need it.

So that it would look something like this,

```
select table1.id from(
...
...
...) 
Having ((A+B)-(C+D+R+F+G)>0)
```

According to this site:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: i know how to use having, but this one is a bit different